# Read multiline JSON in Apache Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to use a JSON file as a small DB. After creating a template table on DataFrame I queried it with SQL and got an exception. Here is my code:

```
val df = sqlCtx.read.json("/path/to/user.json")
df.registerTempTable("user_tt")

val info = sqlCtx.sql("SELECT name FROM user_tt")
info.show()
```

`df.printSchema()` result:

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

My JSON file:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Morty",
  "age": 21
}
```

Exeption:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'name' given input columns: [_corrupt_record];
```

How can I fix it?

*UPD*

`_corrupt_record` is

```
+--------------------+
|     _corrupt_record|
+--------------------+
|                   {|
|            "id": 1,|
|    "name": "Morty",|
|           "age": 21|
|                   }|
+--------------------+
```

*UPD2*

It's weird, but when I rewrite my JSON to make it oneliner, everything works fine.

```
{"id": 1, "name": "Morty", "age": 21}
```

So the problem is in a `newline`.

*UPD3*

I found in docs the next sentence:

> Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object. As a consequence, a regular multi-line JSON file will most often fail.

It isn't convenient to keep JSON in such format. Is there any workaround to get rid of multi-lined structure of JSON or to convert it in oneliner?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.2**

Spark 2.2 introduced <s>`wholeFile`</s> `multiLine` option which can be used to load JSON (not JSONL) files:

```scala
spark.read
  .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .json("/path/to/user.json")
```

See:

- [SPARK-18352](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18352) - *Parse normal, multi-line JSON files (not just JSON Lines)*.
- [SPARK-20980](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20980) - *Rename the option `wholeFile` to `multiLine` for JSON and CSV.*

**Spark < 2.2**

Well, using JSONL formated data may be inconvenient but it I will argue that is not the issue with API but the format itself. JSON is simply not designed to be processed in parallel in distributed systems.

It provides no schema and without making some very specific assumptions about its formatting and shape it is almost impossible to correctly identify top level documents. Arguably this is the worst possible format to imagine to use in systems like Apache Spark. It is also quite tricky and typically impractical to write valid JSON in distributed systems.

That being said, if individual files are valid JSON documents (either single document or an array of documents) you can always try `wholeTextFiles`:

```
spark.read.json(sc.wholeTextFiles("/path/to/user.json").values())
```

Comment: For PySpark currently, the syntax is `spark.read.option("multiline", "true")`

Answer (score 13):

Just to add on to zero323's answer, the option in Spark 2.2+ to read multi-line JSON was renamed to `multiLine` (see the Spark documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets)).

Therefore, the correct syntax is now:

```
spark.read
  .option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
  .json("/path/to/user.json")
```

This happened in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20980.

Comment: Thanks, however, it still reads the first object of my JSON file! Not sure why..

Comment: @DrDEE did you find the solution?