# Spark reading JSON has corrupt column

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Here is my JSON

```
[
    {"string":"string1","int":1,"array":[1,2,3],"dict": {"key": "value1"}},
    {"string":"string2","int":2,"array":[2,4,6],"dict": {"key": "value2"}}
]
```

Here is my parse code:

```
val mdf = sparkSession.read.option("multiline", "true").json("multi2.json")
mdf.show(false)
```

This outputs:

```
+---------------+---------+--------+----+-------+
|_corrupt_record|array    |dict    |int |string |
+---------------+---------+--------+----+-------+
|[              |null     |null    |null|null   |
|null           |[1, 2, 3]|[value1]|1   |string1|
|null           |[2, 4, 6]|[value2]|2   |string2|
|]              |null     |null    |null|null   |
+---------------+---------+--------+----+-------+
```

Why do I have a _corrupt_record, everything looks ok?
Why does the dict column only give the values and not the keys?

Thanks

Comment: use multiLine insted of multiline. it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"multiLine" option is supported from Spark [2.2.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets) onwards.
Contrast it with 2.1.0 [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets)

With > 2.2.0, your example code with the data , works.

Regarding the `dict` column, it will still show the values only but the schema is preserved. You can verify with:

```
scala> mdf.printSchema
root
 |-- array: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- dict: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- int: long (nullable = true)
 |-- string: string (nullable = true)
```

**EDIT**
I realized, much of the info is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545850/read-multiline-json-in-apache-spark)

Comment: Good answer, I was using 2.1 when I thought it was 2.2

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo. Option name is `multiLine` not `multiline`.