# Spark dataframe requires json file as one object in one line?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, record, corrupt

I'm new to spark and trying to use spark to read json file like this. Using spark 2.3 and scala 2.11 on ubuntu18.04, java1.8:

cat my.json:

```
{ "Name":"A", "No_Of_Emp":1, "No_Of_Supervisors":2}
{ "Name":"B", "No_Of_Emp":2, "No_Of_Supervisors":3}
{ "Name":"C", "No_Of_Emp":13,"No_Of_Supervisors":6}
```

And my scala code is:

```
val dir = System.getProperty("user.dir")
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark sql")
.set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", dir)
.setMaster("local[4]");
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()
val df = spark.read.json("my.json")
df.show()
df.printSchema()
df.select("Name").show()
```

OK, everything is fine. But if I change the json file to be multiline, standard json format:

```
[
    {
      "Name": "A",
      "No_Of_Emp": 1,
      "No_Of_Supervisors": 2
    },
    {
      "Name": "B",
      "No_Of_Emp": 2,
      "No_Of_Supervisors": 3
    },
    {
      "Name": "C",
      "No_Of_Emp": 13,
      "No_Of_Supervisors": 6
    }
]
```

Then the program will report error:

```
+--------------------+
|     _corrupt_record|
+--------------------+
|                   [|
|                   {|
|        "Name": "A",|
|      "No_Of_Emp"...|
|      "No_Of_Supe...|
|                  },|
|                   {|
|        "Name": "B",|
|      "No_Of_Emp"...|
|      "No_Of_Supe...|
|                  },|
|                   {|
|        "Name": "C",|
|      "No_Of_Emp"...|
|      "No_Of_Supe...|
|                   }|
|                   ]|
+--------------------+

root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`Name`' given input columns: [_corrupt_record];;
'Project ['Name]
+- Relation[_corrupt_record#0] json
```

I wish to know why this happens? A none standard json file without double [] will work(one object one line), but a more standardized formatted json will be a "corrupt record"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read multiline JSON in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545850/read-multiline-json-in-apache-spark)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [official Document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#json-datasets)

we can get some information about your question

> Spark SQL can automatically infer the schema of a JSON dataset and
> load it as a Dataset[Row]. This conversion can be done using
> SparkSession.read.json() on either a Dataset[String], or a JSON file.
> Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical
> JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid
> JSON object. For more information, please see JSON Lines text format,
> also called newline-delimited JSON. For a regular multi-line JSON
> file, set the multiLine option to true.

so  if  you wanted  run it with your data multiline, set the `multiLine` option to `true`.

here is the example:

```scala
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark sql")
  .set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", dir)
  .setMaster("local[*]")

val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("my.json")
df.show()
df.printSchema()
df.select("Name").show()
```