# Read oneline file into dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the task of reading a one line json file into spark. I´ve thought about either modifying the input file so that it fits `spark.read.json(path)` or read the whole file and modify it inmemory to make it fit the previous line as shown bellow:

```
import spark.implicit._
val file = sc.textFile(path).collect()(0)
val data = file.split("},").map(json => s"$json}")
val ds = data.toSeq.toDF()
```

Is there a way of directly reading the json or read the one line file into multiple rows?

Edit:

Sorry I didn´t crealy explain the json format, all the json in the same line:

```
{"key":"value"},{"key":"value2"},{"key":"value2"}
```

If imported with `spark.read.json(path)` it would only take the first value.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO HugoDife! I believe single line load is what spark.read.json() does and you are perhaps looking for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960160/spark-dataframe-requires-json-file-as-one-object-in-one-line). If not maybe you want to adjust your question with a data example.