# Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file:

```json
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1
  }
}
```

I am trying to read it:

```
val path = "D:/playground/input.json"
val df = spark.read.json(path)
df.show()
```

But getting an error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
> Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed
> when the referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record
> column (named _corrupt_record by default). For example:
> spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count()
> and
> spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).select("_corrupt_record").show().
> Instead, you can cache or save the parsed results and then send the
> same query. For example, val df =
> spark.read.schema(schema).json(file).cache() and then
> df.filter($"_corrupt_record".isNotNull).count().;

So I tried to cache it as they suggest:

```
val path = "D:/playground/input.json"
val df = spark.read.json(path).cache()
df.show()
```

But I keep getting the same error.

Comment: The error clearly says that the problem is that your **JSON** was not read properly. The reason is that **Spark** requires an specific format:  _"Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid JSON object."_ - [**documentation**](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) -  Also, on the [**Scaladoc**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) of the read method, you can see the `multiLine` option which can be useful in this case.

Comment: Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545850/read-multiline-json-in-apache-spark) for some additional info and solution.

Comment: Painful issue poorly explained  imho.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez thanks I didn't know that. Now it's working. Please write your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The problem is with the JSON file. The file : `"D:/playground/input.json"` looks like as you descibed as

```
{
  "a": {
  "b": 1
  }
}
```

This is not right. Spark while processing json data considers each new line as a complete json. Thus it is failing.

You should keep your complete json in a single line in a compact form by removing all white spaces and newlines.

Like

```
{"a":{"b":1}}
```

If you want multiple jsons in a single file keep them like this

```
{"a":{"b":1}}
{"a":{"b":2}}
{"a":{"b":3}} ...
```

For more infos [see](http://jsonlines.org/examples/)

Answer (score 71):

You may try either of these two ways.

**Option-1**: JSON in single line as answered above by @Avishek Bhattacharya.

**Option-2**: Add option to read multi line JSON in the code as follows. You could read the nested attribute also as shown below.

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json("C:\\data\\nested-data.json")
df.select("a.b").show()
```

Here is the output for Option-2.

```
20/07/29 23:14:35 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: show at NestedJsonReader.scala:23, took 0.181579 s
+---+
|  b|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it works

```
 spark.read.json(filename, multiLine=true)
```

Answer (score -1):

**This error means 2 things:**

**1-** either your file format isn't what you think (and you are using the wrong method for it, like its `text` but you mistakenly used `json` method)

**2-** you file doesn't follow the standards for the format you are using (while you used correct method for correct format), this usually happens with json.